# Communicate between View Models in MVVM

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, software-design, solid-principles

I am using MVVM pattern in my project. Here is the pseudo code.

```
class ViewModelA {
     propertyA;
     methodA(); // updates propertyA
}

class ViewModelB {
     methodB() {
     // update properties of ViewModelB
     // Needs to update propertyA of ViewModelA
     }
}
```

I have two view models ViewModelA and ViewModelB. MethodB of ViewModelB needs to update propertyA of ViewModelA.

I can keep a reference of an instance of ViewModelA inside ViewModelB and call methodA to update propertyA of ViewModelA. Is it a good practice to keep a reference of one view model inside another view model in MVVM pattern? Also, would like to know other ways in which View models can update properties of other view models.

Comment: Look at a pub/sub mechanism such as event aggregator. Most of the time you don't want vms to be dependent on each other, sometimes it's ok though but it really depends on usage

Answer (score 1):

you can look at GalaSoft MVVMLight Toolkit it has messaging mechanism. it can be used to communicate beetween viewmodels: http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger, https://mallibone.com/post/mvvmlight-messenger, https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/